# CSS Side Menu Not Returning To Original State After Nav Link Click

Tags: css, html, menu

Please help!!!! I'm including a link to a page with a menu I would like to use for a site I'm building. I can't seem to figure out how to get the ".menu-outer" to reposition itself after I click on a link in the nav. I've tried all sorts of combinations of code but to no available. Could anyone be of any assistance?

http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-side-menu

The Menu has a hover effect that moves the menu back and forth, but I would also like the links to allow the menu to retract once a page link is clicked.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never mentioned using Javascript but here is a version that uses it to close the menu once and item is clicked (**Note:** from the url below a slight change to the css):

```
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu-outer');
var links = document.querySelectorAll('nav ul li a');

var addClass = function(element, className) {
  if (element.classList) {
    element.classList.add(className);
  } else {
    removeClass(element, className);
    element.className = (element.className + ' ' + className).replace(/^\s/, '');
  }
};

var removeClass = function(element, className) {
  if (className.indexOf('*') !== -1) {
    var aryClasses = element.className.split(' ');

    for (var i = 0; i < aryClasses.length; i++) {
      if (aryClasses[i].indexOf(className.replace('*', '')) !== -1) {
        element.removeClass(aryClasses[i]);
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (element.classList) {
      element.classList.remove(className);
    } else {
      element.className = element.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + className.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' ');
    }
  }
};

var open = function() {
  console.log('opening');
  addClass(menu, 'active');
};

var close = function() {
  console.log('closing');
  removeClass(menu, 'active');
};

if (menu) {
  menu.addEventListener('mouseover', open, false);
  menu.addEventListener('mouseout', close, false);

  for (var l = 0; l < links.length; l++) {
    var link = links[l];
    link.addEventListener('click', close, false);
  }
}
```

jQuery would be something like:

```
$('body').on('click', 'nav ul li a', function() {
  $('.menu-outer').removeClass('active');
});

$('body').on('mouseover', '.menu-outer', function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('body').on('mouseout', '.menu-outer', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

http://cssdeck.com/labs/x0lpogde

Comment: Ok, so it works on that site, but not in my browser. I copied everything exact. I'm using Google Chrome, and also tested in Safari and Firefox. The nav is completely disabled. But it's still working on cssdeck.com. And ideas as to why this might be?

Comment: I forgot to mention, in the css, change the `.menu-outer:hover` to `.menu-outer.active`

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, however it isn't working in my browsers. The link you provided me works perfect. when I copy and paste it, the menu doesn't open whether hovering or clicking the menu button.

Comment: Realized a character was missing from my script link. Works fine. Thanks again.